# Cablemodem (SBG6580) firewall denying some outbound traffic? Why? Not configured

Tags: networking, firewall, router, syslog

I finally got around to turning the syslog on for my cablemodem (Motorola Surfboard SBG6580) and I'm seeing about the expected amount of inbound attackage being blocked...

```
2014-05-30 21:59:02     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:58:56 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] UDP 12.230.209.198,4500 --> 66.27.xx.xx,61459 DENY:Firewall interface [IP Fragmented Packet] attack
2014-05-30 21:59:02     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:58:56 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 17.172.232.109,5223 --> 66.27.xx.xx,53814 DENY:Firewall interface access request
2014-05-30 21:59:02     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:58:57 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] UDP 12.230.209.198,443 --> 66.27.xx.xx,53385 DENY: Firewall interface [IP Fragmented Packet] attack
2014-05-30 21:59:02     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:58:57 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] UDP 12.230.209.198,4500 --> 66.27.xx.xx,61459 DENY:Firewall interface [IP Fragmented Packet] attack
2014-05-30 21:59:10     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:59:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] UDP 12.230.209.198,443 --> 66.27.xx.xx,59960 DENY: Firewall interface [IP Fragmented Packet] attack
2014-05-30 21:59:10     Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 31 04:59:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] UDP 12.230.209.198,4500 --> 66.27.xx.xx,61459 DENY:Firewall interface [IP Fragmented Packet] attack
```

...and that's great.  (Sad, but great.)

But I'm also seeing a HUGE amount of what appears to be denied outbound connectivity:

```
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58969 --> 38.81.66.127,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request 
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58969 --> 38.81.66.127,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request 
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58965 --> 162.222.41.13,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request 
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58965 --> 162.222.41.13,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request 
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58964 --> 38.81.66.179,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request 
2014-05-30 16:30:10 Local0.Alert    192.168.111.1   May 30 23:30:04 2014 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.111.1] TCP 192.168.111.100,58964 --> 38.81.66.179,443 DENY: Inbound or outbound access request
```

...and

1. Spot checking suggests that it's all legitimate traffic (Opening connections to CrashPlan, etc.),
2. I have no restrictions configured in the modem; I don't see why it should be blocking anything.

Am I misreading the log entry, and it's not actually being denied?  (Seems unlikely.)  Is the ISP (TWC) pushing deny tables that are not exposed in the UI?  (Tinfoil hat too tight.)

I'm confused.  (The good news, such as it is, is that AFAIK I'm not experiencing any actual issues... but maybe I am; tough to tell.)

Thanks.

Comment: General FYI: Terminology matters, as modems don't have firewalls, only routers, PCs, and servers do _(modems are incapable of having a firewall as modems and routers literally use two completely different programming languages and protocols with neither understanding the others' protocols)_. Regardless of what an OEM chooses to call their equipment, the Surfboard SBG6580, and others like it, are modem+router combos, with this question applying only to the router portion.

Answer (score 0):

I googled about motorola modem firewall.. Try to configure or disable the firewall.

If it does NAPT then should still have NAPT there as a protection. If not then if  you have another NAPT device you'll have NAPT as protection! (with your OS software firewall  and if you have another hardware firewall then you'll have that)

Those inbound attacks would be blocked at that device, by NAPT anyway even without a firewall. (where there's no port forwarding on the ports they attack)

There is a user guide for your device here

http://www.arrisi.com/modems/datasheet/SBG6580/SBG6580_UserGuide.pdf

Perhaps also see if you can telnet or ssh to it and use iptables and configure it that way. one person here mentions iptables and a similar model number device    (apparently comcast is apparently ISP that bought motorola modems and use them and this link mentions iptables in the context of an SB6141, though it's not clear from that whether it does use it)

http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Basic-Internet-Connectivity-And/Motorola-SB6141-Not-Receiving-New-Configuration-Boot-File/td-p/1818941

If it does use iptables then run the command `iptables -L` and see if you see any rules there that might be a culprit.

Further, this post

http://community.callofduty.com/thread/100463756
"Under the firewall settings, by default the only thing checked was IP flood detection and firewall protection.  I unchecked both."

You could experiment with checking one and not the other.

It is accessed by local ip of 192.168.0.1 and does DHCP, and even has a firewall, so i'm confidently assuming that if you do ipconfig it'll show you gateway of 192.168.0.1 or whatever the local ip is, so  clearly does NAT.  So disabling the firewall should be ok. That link above concurs.

http://portforward.com/english/routers/firewalling/Motorola/SBG6580/defaultguide.htm

[image]

Comment: It's in a NAT/PAT role, and I actually have a second NAT/PAT router between it and most of the infrastructure -- but I'd really like to understand why it's denying inside-to-outside traffic.  

(Manual is, unfortunately, very consumer-grade; doesn't even discuss the firewall configuration, syslog, etc.)

Comment: @lairdb a post at the callofduty link mentioned a firewall settings section and an "IP flood detection" and "firewall protection" option, I guess you don't see those.  Unfortunately, the closest I see in the manual is parental block. Have you tried seeing if you can telnet or ssh to it? what ports it has open(scan with nmap)

Comment: @lairdb let the people know if you can SSH or telnet to it, it' be interesting, you could perhaps then see the output of `iptables -L`. And also i've added a pic from portforward.com relating to the firewall on that model.  Look at the top of the window it says status, basic, advanced, **FIREWALL** , parental control, wireless, vpn, logout. See Firewall there? On your device? That is for that model.

Comment: I nmapped it, and 22 and 23 come back as filtered -- there may be some incantation to get to them, but not directly.

Comment: There do seem to be quite a few versions of the firmware -- my header menu is a little simpler: ![header](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v430/lairdb/LinkedImages/2014-06-0217_40_23-ResidentialGatewayConfiguration_Status-Connection.png).  I have turned off the "firewall" (since this is the outer of two routers) and the syslog "DENY" messages have stopped.  ![off](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v430/lairdb/LinkedImages/2014-06-0217_42_28-ResidentialGatewayConfiguration_Firewall-WebContentFilter.png)  (Hmm -- no embedded images in comments?  Sorry; click through.)

Comment: @lairdb FYI for TCP e.g. telnet and ssh, 'filtered' is very much closed. 'closed' means it gives some response indicating that it's closed.  'filtered' means it gives no response at all i.e. some firewall is making it blocking the typical closed response.

Comment: General FYI: Terminology matters, as modems don't have firewalls, only routers, PCs, and servers do _(modems are incapable of having a firewall as modems and routers literally use two completely different programming languages and protocols with neither understanding the others' protocols)_. Regardless of what an OEM chooses to call their equipment, the Surfboard SBG6580, and others like it, are modem+router combos, with the OP's question, and this answer, applying only to the router portion.

Comment: @JW0914 What on earth. I never  said a modem has a firewall!! I said a device can have a modem in it and a router in it and a firewall in it.  Technically routing and doing-firewall are separate functions. There's no technical reason why one would have to say "oh you put a modem in the router, now you gotta take out the firewall" or "oh there's no modem in the modem-router  anymore, so now it's just a router so now you can put a firewall in there".  'cos that logic would be wrong. it's not like you can't have a firewall in there when a modem is added to it!

Comment: @JW0914  If we move to in practise rather than theory, then, (unless things have changed, and maybe they have),  when a device has a modem in there, along with the router in there, then they put less features in the routing so eg the routing is rubbish(just two sides), the routing is so limited that some don't even call it a router , and then there tends to be no firewall in there either.

Comment: @barlop I commented since the distinction was never made that a modem itself can never have a firewall, as it doesn't use networking or communication protocols required to do so. A modem has no ability to route traffic, which is why routers exist, and is literally a completely different piece of hardware as a router _(AFAIK modem+router combos even keep the two separate on the PCB)_, they are not inter-changeable, and both have two completely different purposes which the other cannot be used for _(beyond sending and receiving the WAN signal, neither can directly communicate with the other)_.

Comment: @JW0914  well of course I agree with that!